# What is global memory size of my device?

Tags: memory, cuda

I have Tesla C2075. I wanted to know global memory size. So I ran `deviceQuery` SDK sample. It reports me 4GB of global memory but when I run `nvidia-smi` -q, it reports 6GB of global memory. Why this mismatch occurs? Is some memory specially dedicated for OS?
./deviceQuery reports:

> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> Found 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
>
> Device 0: "Tesla C2075"
> CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.0 / 5.0
> CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
> Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294967295 bytes)

nvidia-smi -q output:

> Memory Usage
> Total                   : 5375 MB
> Used                    : 39 MB
> Free                    : 5336 MB

Comment: Are you sure that 4GB is reported? With ECC on I would expect some reduction from the 6GB (12.5% to be precise), but not a total of 2GB.

Comment: I don't use 32-bit myself, so I can't verify, but I'm wondering if this might be a 32-bit OS issue. As in, it can only address 4GB of global memory, so that is what it reports. Not necessarily the physical amount available.

Comment: Ohh...can be.. not sure though

Comment: Pointer sizes are always the same between the host and the driver/device in CUDA, so if you have a 32 bit OS, your GPU should be using 32 bit pointers too. That will be the problem, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You're running 32-bit Linux, so you will only have 4GB of device memory available to your process.

The device still has 6GB, so if you have two processes sharing the device then between them they can occupy the full 6GB, but each process can only use 4GB.

Comment: So If I want to access all memory in my GPU then should I use 64bit system?

Comment: If you want to access all memory in your GPU *from a single process*, then yes. A 32-bit pointer can point to a maximum 4 gigabytes, so it's easy to see why you need a bigger pointer to be able to address the larger memory. The same applies on the CPU, each 32-bit process has a 4GB limit (actually less since the OS needs some).

Comment: @Tom, what you are saying is true of CPUs, but it is quite possible that CUDA's driver support requires a 64-bit kernel to access the full 64 bits' worth of video memory.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware: I think you've misunderstood since that's exactly my point: if you have a 32-bit application you can only address 4GB of memory. If you have a 64-bit application then not only can you address all of the GPU memory, but you also get UVA which means that GPU and CPU pointers live in separate spaces and you can determine where data is based on the pointer value.

Comment: Tom, Why do you think the CUDA driver does not require a 64-bit kernel to support a GPU board with >4GB of RAM?  That is a very different constraint than anything you have raised in your comments, and speaking as the initial implementor of CUDA's 64-bit support, it wouldn't surprise me in the least if 64-bit kernel support were required.  I have not tried running a 6G board on a 32-bit kernel, and won't believe it works until I see it.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware: You made me doubt myself so I had to check! Two processes on a 32-bit OS can, between them, use > 4GB. If username_4567 can run the experiment, that'd be cool!

Comment: Tom, were you able to use >4GB of video memory on a CUDA-capable GPU? That is the only thing I have been saying may not work.  If you refer back to my original comment, I still stand by it verbatim: "It is quite possible that CUDA's driver support requires a 64-bit kernel to access the full 64-bits' worth of VIDEO MEMORY." (emphasis added)

Comment: I still stand by my comment verbatim too :-) "Two processes on a 32-bit OS can, between them, use > 4GB", in other words the constrain is that you cannot map the full 6GB into the process since device pointers are the same size as host pointers - 32-bits - and mapping >4GB would be impossible. Sure, I haven't run this (I'm not about to install a new OS for this comment thread!) and if you don't believe me then we'll just have to hope @username_4567 can run the experiment.